# ReportViewer "Export to Excel" adds decimal to percentage values. How can I override this?

Tags: asp.net, excel, reportviewer

I have a ReportViewer control on my aspx page that renders a nice report with one of the columns being a percentage.  I have put the format of the cell as p0 and it works fine.  Users that export the report to excel notice that a decimal appears after the value.

Ie. What used to be "20%" is now "20.%".  How can I get rid of the "."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this was made with CR, I've found that if a report is going to consistently be exported to Excel, it's best to remove ALL formatting that CR has/does.  Otherwise you'll get weird anomalies like what you're experiencing and will save you a lot of grief down the road.

What I've done for some of my users is create one report with no formatting, specifically for exporting, and one report with all the bells and whistles of CR.