# crystal report 9

Tags: crystal-reports

new page break is not working when exporting from Crystal report 9 using visual studio studio.net.
I have set the below options in crystal report 9 design

paper size is a3 and orientation is landscape.
I have created 2 report groups (date and org unit)
I want a page break after every new date and after every new org unit.
I have already set the new page after in group footer1 and group footer 2.

when i export to excel it doesn't break the page after each group is changed.
Can anybody help me to resolve this issue.

thanks
bby

Answer (score 2):

I said this in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570434/reportviewer-export-to-excel-adds-decimal-to-percentage-values-how-can-i-overrid/570507#570507) regarding exporting to Excel:

> If this was made with CR, I've found
>   that if a report is going to
>   consistently be exported to Excel,
>   it's best to remove ALL formatting
>   that CR has/does. Otherwise you'll get
>   weird anomalies like what you're
>   experiencing and will save you a lot
>   of grief down the road.
>
> What I've done for some of my users is
>   create one report with no formatting,
>   specifically for exporting, and one
>   report with all the bells and whistles
>   of CR.

Answer (score 2):

Page breaks are not understood by Excel during the export.  The best bet is to do a grouping on the report and render them as tabs in the Excel document.

Answer (score 1):

Crystal has a long history of problems when exporting to excel.  There are quite a few tips about on how to get both good looking reports on the screen and in an Excel worksheet.  There is no one answer for your problem, as it really depends on just how your report is structured.  I googled on "crystal reports page break excel export" and get plenty of material to look at.  For example:
[Exporting to Excel in Crystal Reports .NET - Perfect Excel Exports](http://aspalliance.com/478_Exporting_to_Excel_in_Crystal_Reports_NET__Perfect_Excel_Exports.all)

Comment: Actually I have already read the link and i put the code accordingly but my issue is only that it is not doing the page breaks properly after every new group.alignment and other formatting is good in excel.